# Blazor Azure Authentication response url sits at https://localhost:44398/signin-oidc

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Web App which uses Azure (MSAL) for authentication. When started from VS, it goes through the 2 factor authentication which is set up and afterwards it forwards correctly to the specified response url.
The login GET is:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/64f2c3d9-1234-1234-1234-24ca4bd2b68c/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6d3a12cd-1234-1234-1234-36705c3599c9&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44398%2Fsignin-oidc&
response_type=code&
scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20User.Read&
response_mode=form_post&
nonce=637485855282505544.OTY5ZTVlZGMtOTJhZS00NzhiLWIwNGMtZWIyZTcwNGNmNWJjMWNlYjU0OTAtNDBhMS00M2YyLWIzNDEtYTc4ZjU5NDczMWEz&client_info=1&x-client-brkrver=IDWeb.1.5.1.0&state=CfDJ8GEtZIi24ztJtFeZqYrn2ijai5MWeqn6_tHixtusaYfm_AKkDj6wEiibQqSQ1WT5rEQJyzdbY-TarMv5mVAFV-YUdP0xDMJCpggQgOhwhhASOiahqOPSICMG0y9VQ6s5cpQmbCqCAS9ksdV6Rfrd8OfobtVc3Kj1mLACiJi44i8crlSFSHYjihjvv-uR-92lGtxcAwAHmG5dE_N5corbNW6Ey0XblE1g-ZwGn1RQKPifcW8AvAuadE2-EujLRsSO4Qt9-7IEdimEfYLEoq5A_DedZLPLaTk4JSKB8ZzRwLaT&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.7.1.0
```

The issue is that after authentication, my web app sits at:
https://localhost:44398/signin-oidc
and does nothing.
What do I do wrong?

thanks!

Comment: Did it not return an authorization code?

Comment: What do you expect it to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `response_mode=form_post` to `response_mode=query`, and then execute the request for the URL in the browser, and you will get the **authorization code**.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=e983d29f-8f89-43c2-b32d-a82a84caa6b8&
redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&
response_type=code&
scope=openid profile offline_access User.Read&
response_mode=query&
nonce=637485855282505544.OTY5ZTVlZGMtOTJhZS00NzhiLWIwNGMtZWIyZTcwNGNmNWJjMWNlYjU0OTAtNDBhMS00M2YyLWIzNDEtYTc4ZjU5NDczMWEz&client_info=1&x-client-brkrver=IDWeb.1.5.1.0&state=CfDJ8GEtZIi24ztJtFeZqYrn2ijai5MWeqn6_tHixtusaYfm_AKkDj6wEiibQqSQ1WT5rEQJyzdbY-TarMv5mVAFV-YUdP0xDMJCpggQgOhwhhASOiahqOPSICMG0y9VQ6s5cpQmbCqCAS9ksdV6Rfrd8OfobtVc3Kj1mLACiJi44i8crlSFSHYjihjvv-uR-92lGtxcAwAHmG5dE_N5corbNW6Ey0XblE1g-ZwGn1RQKPifcW8AvAuadE2-EujLRsSO4Qt9-7IEdimEfYLEoq5A_DedZLPLaTk4JSKB8ZzRwLaT&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.7.1.0
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, the whole setup is more complicated and I was hoping to only pass on the, what I thought was, crucial piece. I created a website with VS and used Azure authentication and it works just fine. It returns to the right place, the view that was asking for authentication and that's it. Then I took the important parts and copied it to my existing web app, launch settings, startup, appsettings, keys, etc. and ran that. Result: EXACT same url on the way to lauthentication except the nonce and the result is that it is stuck at that response url. That's it. It totally signed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I didn't have in Startup.cs the following to lines (indented to identify) between

```
app.UseRounting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints();
```